# How to draw an image from multiple sprites?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm new to programming, trying to make a simple Snake game.

I uploaded three images (16x16px) of a snake (head, body, tail) to a list and wanted to display it with a for loop (each sprite next to each other) but I failed. All I can do is draw the images which are overwriting the last one in my update() method.

I've made some code like adding second [1] (snake_body) to my snake_head image, but I couldn't find a way to display it in a for loop next to each other.

here's some code:

```
class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, apples_eaten):
        # Initialize
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = game.screen
        self.screen_rect = game.screen.get_rect()

        # Movement
        self.direction = 'left'
        self.step = 10

        # Init stats
        self.apples_eaten = 0
        self.current_sprite = 0

        # Create sprites
        self.sprites = []
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Fox\Desktop\Python\Snake\Sprites\Snake\Snake_head.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Fox\Desktop\Python\Snake\Sprites\Snake\Snake_body.png'))
        for apple in range(apples_eaten):
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Fox\Desktop\Python\Snake\Sprites\Snake\Snake_body.png'))
        self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Fox\Desktop\Python\Snake\Sprites\Snake\Snake_tail.png'))

        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect = self.screen_rect.center

    def update(self):
        self.current_sprite += 1
        if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
```

How I can draw images from sprite next to each other in a loop? (or any other way?)

I want to make one moving image from 3 sprites linked to each other.

Comment: you need also list with positions for all sprites. And later you have to get sprite from one list and its position from another list. OR you should use real sprite - `pygame.sprite.Sprite` because at this moment you use only `Surface` (`image.load` gives `Surface`). And `Sprite` keeps image as `Surface` and its position as `pygame.Rect`

Answer (score 0):

You have list of images but you need also list of positions.
Every sprite needs own position but you use the same `rect` for all images.

```
sprites   = [image1, image2, image3]
positions = [pos1, pos2, pos3]
```

and later

```
img = sprites[self.current_sprite]
pos = positions[self.current_sprite]

screen.blit(img, pos)
```

---

Or you should keep it as pairs `(image, position)

```
sprites = [(image1, pos1), (image2, pos2), (image3, pos3)]
```

and do

```
img, pos = sprites[self.current_sprite]

screen.blit(img, pos)
```

---

PyGame has even real [pygame.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) which can keep image ([pygame.Surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)) and positon ([pygame.Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)). Function `image.load` gives you only `pygame.Surface`.

But for snake which can change its length I would rather keep snake positions as list (without positions of apple and other objects)

```
snake = [pos1, pos2, pos3, ..., posN]
```

and I would use first position to draw image with `head`, last position to draw image with `tail`, and other positions to draw images with `body`.

```
img = head
pos = snake[0]

screen.blit(img, pos)

img = tail
pos = snake[-1]

screen.blit(img, pos)

img = body
for pos in snake[1:-1]
    screen.blit(img, pos)
```

And when it has to move then I would add new position at the beginning of list and remove last position from list. And when snake eats apple then I would keep last position on list to make snake longer.

Comment: So you mean, i need only list of 3 sprites (head, body, tail) and then i should increase the lenght of position list, and then blit the body on the increased position list?
I've written to you on fb, god bless you are from same country and your name is same as mine, if you have a time, i just wanted to ask about why i get minus score with my question

Comment: yes, in snake you may use list with 3 sprites and separated list with all positions of parts of snake - it may have more than 3 elements because snake may change length when it eats apple.

Comment: question can be downvoted because snake is popular game and probably you may find many questions which show code for snake. When other users will search answers then Stackoverflow will use this to suggest answers with more points so people may find better question and answer.

Comment: Okay, understood, I asked about drawing image in loop, not about a game ;) Anyway, thank you, but I've search alot on Stackoverflow about this and only your answer satisfied my needs, I didn't see this answer in any topic and in any video tutorials (I dont feel my search was bad)